# Problemas com Login pela Api do google

Tags: php, google-openid

Boa noite estou usando o login do google em meu site.
fiz com java script mais php  e funcionanormal.

meu problema é no meu aplicativo que é uma webview

como não pode abrir outra aba ele abre na mesma a tela para logar no google e depois disso a tela fica em branca e não volta pro site

alguém saberia como fazer o loguin do google na mesma tela sem que precise abrir uma nova tab?

Comment: Acredito que falta você configurar alguma url de redirecionamento na api do google.

Comment: configurei , minha dúvia he como ele retorna os dados? é um post ? se for qulal é a variavel que tenho q pegar para ler o token de autorização e comparar se é valido ?